# How to collect the user input when make a call using Twilio API?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am developing a simple application in C# which

- Trigger a call using Twilio
- receiver to press * after receiving the call and finish the call after pressing *
- Provide the status completed if user pressed * otherwise provide different status.

I was able to make a call but not able to receive the user input Or status, I tried `finishOnKey()` but that didn't work, and it always provides status as completed. I didn't get much help from Twilio code sample, can someone redirect to correct article or provide the code to accomplish above.

Comment: Please share the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Once a call is answered successfully, it doesn't matter how the call is finished, the final status it reaches will be "completed". You can see more about [Twilio call statuses in this documentation](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132547-What-are-the-Possible-Call-Statuses-and-What-do-They-Mean-). You can see that the final call statuses could be:

- completed: call was answered successfully and then finished
- no-answer: Twilio dialled the number but there was no answer before the timeout
- busy: Twilio dialled the number but received a busy signal
- cancelled: The number was dialled, but the call was then cancelled using the API before answering
- failed: the carrier couldn't connect the call

If you are using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) to take the user input, you should ensure you have set the [`action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action) to a URL in your application. That URL will receive a new webhook request when the user presses a digit. For example:

```xml
<Response>
  <Gather action="/gather_results" digits="1">
    <Say>... your content goes here ...</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

With the above TwiML a user would only have to press 1 key before the call is moved to the next stage and the webhook '/gather_results'.

The request to the `/gather_results` endpoint would include a body with a `Digits` parameter. If the user pressed "*" then the body of the request would include `Digits=*`, if the user pressed "1" then it would include `Digits=1`. You could then choose to do whatever you like with those results, including hanging up the call or recording the submitted digits.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: apologies for delayed response as we were working on twilio license and all. here is the code which is actually read out the digit and we have to enter to verify. how to make this code to work like we just press * and it verify.TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

            VerificationResource verification;
            
                verification = VerificationResource.Create(
                    to: "+1XXXXX",
                    channel: "call",
                    pathServiceSid: "VAXXXXX",
                    locale: "en"
                );

Comment: Hello, not sure what you’re asking now. Can you clarify please?

Comment: Here is the requirement - Trigger a call using Twilio
receiver to press * after receiving the call and finish the call after pressing *
Provide the status completed if user pressed * otherwise provide different status.